# How to get the first span tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get the first and second span tags separately. I've tried everything that can be tried. How can I get it separately?

```html
<td class="searchResultsDateValue">
       <span>01 December</span>
       <br>
       <span>2019</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like

```
span1, span2 = soup.find('td', {'class': 'searchResultsDateValue'}).find_all('span')
```

that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html = """<td class="searchResultsDateValue"><span>01 December</span> <br><span>2019</span></td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find("td", "searchResultsDateValue")
lis = div.find_all('span')
print(lis)
```